# Is Stop server in IIS Manager the same as iisReset /stop?

Tags: iis-7

I notice when I click Stop server on  IIS Manager, some w3wp.exe is still running. But I run  `iisReset /stop`, they all exist.

I thought Stop server is the same as `iisReset /stop`, but apparently they are slightly different. What's the difference?

Comment: It is not open sourced, so no way to give you an answer.

Comment: Your car is not open sourced, but I assume you still know the differences between the two or three pedals under you feet.